# C++ Iterating with for loop and calling a function within it

Tags: c++, abstraction

So I've been following some tutorials on Udemy for C++ and so far it's been incredibly informative and clear however I'm a little stumped by how a for function is calling another function.

So my first function is;

EDIT
I've included use namespace std so being the String rather than std::

```
string getGuess()
{
    cout << "Enter your guess" << endl;
    Guess = "";
    getLine(cin,Guess);
    cout << "Your guess was: " << Guess << endl; 
    return Guess;
}
```

And then to iterate through this function 5 times so they can guess 5 times I'm writing

```
void play()
{
    constexpr int guessTimes = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i<=guessTimes ; i++)
    {
        getGuess();
    }
}
```

Now this all makes sense to me, however the next part of the tutorial is abstracting the;

```
cout << "Your guess was: " << Guess << endl;
```

The for function is then rewritten as so;

```
void play()
{
    constexpr int guessTimes = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i<=guessTimes ; i++)
    {
        string Guess = getGuess();
        cout << "Your guess was: " << Guess << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand how it's now running the getGuess function as it's now applied to a new String variable which in itself I find quite strange, some clarification of how the fundamentals of this process works would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `i<=guessTimes` this will iterate 6 times not 5

Comment: What is `String`?  There is a `std::string` in C++, but it is not `String`.

Comment: `int guessTimes = 5` declares an `int`, and initialises it with an expression which has the value 5. `String Guess = getGuess();` declares a `String` and initialises it with an expression that has a value determined by running the function `getGuess` and seeing what is `return`ed

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Udemy is a "teaching website", OP probably isn't exposed to C++ unadulterated by "simplifications" at this point

Comment: `[teach-me]` You need to understand what `return` means in C++. Also, please use the right terminology: " it's now applied to a new String variable" should rather be "the value returned by getGuess() is *assigned* to a new string variable". "Abstracting the line" should probably be "moving the line".

Comment: @Arkadiy no, the new String variable is *initialised* with the return value of `getGuess()`. There is no use of `String & operator=(const String &)` here

Comment: @Caleth - agreed, I was just trying to simplify for the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably overthinking it. There's really not much to explain.

Do you find this strange?

```
string x = "hello";
```

Do you find this strange?

```
string y = x;
```

Then you shouldn't find this strange

```
string z = f();
```

`"hello"`, `x` and `f()` are all examples of expressions. Expressions are evaluated to produce values. `f()` is an expression that calls the function `f`. The return value of the function `f` is the value of the expression. One of the things you can do with a value is assign it to another variable.